# Vue child component unreactive

Tags: vue.js, vuex

In an application with a Vuex store, there's a `getQueryParams` getter which returns an object containing the parameters being passed to a database query. If there are any parameters (i.e. the user has queried something) then I'd like to display a banner on the page indicating what they hav edone so (amongst other things). Initially I dealt with this by putting the following in the page:

```
<v-row
  v-if="Object.keys(getQueryParams).length >= 1"
>
  <!-- various elements including a v-alert... -->
</v-row>
```

Also:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters("queryStore", ['getQueryParams']),
 ...
}
```

And, in the store:

```
const getters = {
  getQueryParams(state) {
    return state.queryParams;
  },
  ...
}
```

This behaved as expected, causing the banner to appear the moment the store changed.
Later, needing to use this in more than one place, I moved it to a separate QueryBanner component. At that point, the banner stopped appearing when the result of getQueryParams changed. I can see the store change using the Vue dev tools, but e.g. a console.log in the new component showing the output of getQueryParams doesn't. Why might this be?

EDIT:

No luck from this, either:

```
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('multiTagsStore', ["getQueryParams"]),
    queryStore() {
      return this.$store.getters["multiTagsStore/getQueryParams"];
    }
  },
  watch: {
    queryStore(val) {
      if (Object.keys(val).length > 0) {
        this.showBanner = true;
      }
      else {
        this.showBanner = false;
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All attempts to watch the content of the store within the child component have resulted in failure. But, I was able to work around this by using `Object.keys(getQueryParams).length > 0` in the parent and passing this value as a prop to the child. I.e.

```
<ResultPreviewBanner :show-banner="Object.keys(getQueryParams).length > 0" />
```

...and:

```
<v-row
  v-if="showBanner"
>
```

...in the child.

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys() returns an array that is not reactive, so it is not being re-evaluated.
Try to create another computed:

```
computed: {
  queryParamsExist () {
    return Object.keys(this.getQueryParams).length
  }
}
```

Use that computed in the template:

```
<v-row v-if="queryParamsExist"> 
  <!-- various elements -->
</v-row>
```

Comment: I also tried creating a computed property along the lines of what you describe, and then a watcher on that computed property, but with no success with either of these approaches.

Comment: well, have you tried to render your `getQueryParams` value somewhere outside v-if, but on this page? I mean whether is it accessed properly inside the component? Try to access it using `this.$store.getters` instead of mapGetters,

Comment: I have; getQueryParams shows the expected contents. I can see that the store is correct with the Vue dev tools as well. this.$store.getters in the computed property didn't make any difference, but I will have to try again next time I have a moment. Perhaps putting that in the computed property and the Object.keys in a watcher may do it.